# How to cut off int at the end of a line

Tags: ruby

I have a txt file similar to the following:

```
f1, max, inputs: 10 2 4

f2, sum, inputs: 2 4 5

f3, prod, inputs: 6 5
```

I should find the max from the line where the `max` is stated (10), print the sum of the numbers from where the `sum` is (11), and the product from where the `prod` is (30).

My code looks like this:

```
f = File.open("test.txt") or die "Unable to open file..."
contentArray=[]
f.each_line {|line|
    contentArray.push line
}

i=0
while i<contentArray.size() do
    if contentArray[i].include? "max"
        print "max is here"
        i+=1
    elsif contentArray[i].include? "sum"
        print "sum is here"
        i+=1
    elsif contentArray[i].include? "prod"
        print "prod is here"
        i+=1
    end
end
```

I can find which line has the max, sum, or prod string, but I don't know how I should cut off the integers from the end and do the maths with them.

Comment: When asking how to do something, we expect you to show us evidence of your effort toward solving it. While you show how you're looping, you don't show any effort toward solving the part you're asking about. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you. See "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give something like this a shot:

```
content_ary.each do |content_str|
  segments_ary = content_str.split(':')
  integers_ary = segments_ary[1].strip.split(' ').map{|int_str| int_str.to_i}
  tags_ary = segments_ary[0].strip.split(',')
  case tags_ary[1].strip
  when "max"
    puts "max is here"
    puts "#{integers_ary}"
  when "sum"
    puts "sum is here"
    puts "#{integers_ary}"
  when "prod"
    puts "prod is here"
    puts "#{integers_ary}"
  end
end
```

First, it's more rubyish to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`. So, `content_ary`, not `contentArray`.

Then, do `content_ary.each do |content_str|` instead of `while i < contentArray.size()`. Then you don't have to mess wit `i+=1`.

Next,

```
segments_ary = content_str.split(':')
```

splits each line into a two-element array with each element begin the content to the left and right of ':'.

```
integers_ary = segments_ary[1].strip.split(' ').map{|int_str| int_str.to_i}
```

extracts your integers on the right-hand side:

```
  segments_ary[1]              <= selects the right-hand side
  strip                        <= removes leading and trailing white spaces
  split(' ')                   <= creates an array of strings
  map{|int_str| int_str.to_i}  <= converts the strings to integers
```

then:
      tags_ary = segments_ary[0].strip.split(',')

extracts the tags on the left-hand side of the ':'.

Now, use a `case` statement instead of the `if... elsif... elsif`.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def print_totals(fname)
  File.foreach(fname) do |line|
    _, op, _, *a = line.split(/, *|: *| +(?=\d)/)
    a.map!(&:to_i)
    tot = a.reduce do |t,n|
      case op
      when 'max'  then [t,n].max
      when 'sum'  then t+n
      when 'prod' then t*n
      end
    end
    puts "%s %s = %d" % [op, a, tot]
  end
end
```

`line.split(/, *|: *| +(?=\d)/)` reads, "split `line` on a) a comma followed by zero or more spaces or b) a colon followed by zero or more spaces or c) one or more spaces followed by a digit" (`(?=\d)` being a *positive lookahead*). That line operates as follows.

```
line = "f1, max, inputs: 10 2 4"
_, op, _, *a = line.split(/, *|: *| +(?=\d)/)
   #=> ["f1", "max", "inputs", "10", "2", "4"]
op #=> "max"
a  #=> ["10", "2", "4"]
```

**Example**

First create a test file.

```
contents =<<-_
f1, max, inputs: 10 2 4
f2, sum, inputs: 2 4 5
f3, prod, inputs: 6 5
_

FName = 'temp'
File.write(FName, contents)
  #=> 69
```

Confirm its contents.

```
puts File.read(FName)
f1, max, inputs: 10 2 4
f2, sum, inputs: 2 4 5
f3, prod, inputs: 6 5
```

Print the desired results.

```
print_totals FName
max [10, 2, 4] = 10
sum [2, 4, 5] = 11
prod [6, 5] = 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
content_array = [
  'f1, max, inputs: 10 2 4',
  'f2, sum, inputs: 2 4 5',
  'f3, prod, inputs: 6 5'
]
```

I'd solve the basic problem like this:

```
content_array.each do |li|
  values = li.scan(/\b \d+ \b/x).map(&:to_i)

  operation, result = case li
          when /\b max \b/x
            ['max', values.max] 
          when /\b sum \b/x
            ['sum', values.sum]
          when /\b prod \b/x
            ['prod', values.inject(:*)]
          end
  puts "#{operation}: #{result}"
end
```

Which outputs:

```
max: 10
sum: 11
prod: 30
```

Doing it this way will handle more numbers being added to the ends of the lines without changes to the code.

If I added an additional record:

```
'f4, prod, inputs: 6 5 4 3 2'
```

I'd get:

```
prod: 720
```

Breaking it down:

```
values = li.scan(/\b \d+ \b/x) # => ["10", "2", "4"], ["2", "4", "5"], ["6", "5"]
  .map(&:to_i)                 # => [10, 2, 4],       [2, 4, 5],       [6, 5]
```

Where `/\b \d+ \b/x` is a Regexp pattern that searches for stand-alone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for sure, that the first field ('f1',....) always starts with an alphabetic character, a cheap solution would be to simply split the line on spaces:

```
fields = line.split(' ')
```

or

```
fields = line.split(/\s/)
```

depending on your taste.

You get the numbers then by

```
numbers = fields.select { |element| /^\d/ =~ element }.map(&:to_i)
```

As a side effect, you also get the operators for free, for example

```
case fields[1]
when 'sum,'
  result = numbers.reduce(:+)
when 'max,'
  ...
end
```

Of course this assumes that the input corresponds strictly to this formatting. If this can not be ensured (for instance because the input file is manually created by a human being), you should add some sanitary checks on the input format.